UI automation of avalonia with pywinauto
i am working on some UI automation, and so far worked with pywinauto to do that, but now i want to automate an application, that used avalonia for its UI and pywinauto doesn't seem to be able to access the UI properly. For context: pywinauto offers a function called print_control_identifiers, which gives you all the handles etc. you need to select the elements of the UI, but for this app the function doesn't give me any handles to work with. The only idea i have is, that i might be a similar problem pywinauto (according to docs) can have with chrome, where a specific parameter need to be set, for pywinauto to access the renderer (or with a renderer, I'm not 100% sure).
I also tried to add the parameter used to work with chrome and pywinauto (--force_renderer_accessibility), but it didn't solve the problem. maybe there is a avalonia version of this i could use.
Now i want to either be able to use pywinauto with avalonia, or maybe anybody knows another UI automation module for python i could use instead.
you can use one of the demo UIs avalonia provides (https://avaloniaui.net/showcase ; i tried icon8 Lunacy and the could reproduce the issue there) and a very simple python script
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title="Lunacy", timeout=100)  
window = app.window(title_re="Lunacy")
window.set_focus()    # used this to confirm the windows got connected
window.print_control_identifiers()


Maybe this branch with DLL injection into WPF app is helpful: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/pull/1210 Because Avalonia is built on top of XAML which is WPF-related. I didn't try any demo from Avalonia yet.

on first glance it looks very promising, will update after i get through it

I tried using the dotnet injection, but the results look like the avalonia UI doesnt use wpf, unless there are still some big issues in the merge request which i hope there arent.
When install from the branch, and run a basic script to print the control identifiers, it fails, due to a missing pid down the line (TypeError: OpenProcess() argument 3 [thats the pid] must be int, not None),which doesnt happen if i use uia or win32

thanks for the feedback. Maybe XAML has some differences with normal WPF. Unfortunately I'm not very active in maintenance last few years. So I can't provide any time estimations right now. Sorry.

Did you try to have a look at the inspection tools described in the "Getting started" page of pywinauto ?
I think they can provide you the control identifiers you are looking for.

Yes tried the inspection tool as well with the same results
